# Carousel of sliding images not looping when the iteration is done?

Tags: javascript, html, image, carousel, slideshow

I found a tutorial for a image carousel on youtube. I put it in one website and it worked fine, but now I am trying to implement it to another website and it doesn't loop. At the end of the iteration the image just disapears from the website. From what I can tell the code is the same in both the files. What could be wrong here?

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.lenght) {myIndex = 1}
    x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 1000);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img class="mySlides" src="photo/banner.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="photo/banner2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="photo/banner3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="photo/banner4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="photo/banner5.jpg" style="width:100%">
</section>
```

Comment: You should firstly correct the `x.lenght` typo but then change the reset index to zero as Javascript uses zero based arrays - so `1` refers to the 2nd image in the collection which explains why the 1st image `disappears`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's not a typo in the question, change

```
if (myIndex > x.lenght) {myIndex = 1}
```

to

```
if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the named function being called as you are here you can use anonymous functions like this.

I suspect the whole problem revolved around the fact that you reset the index to 1 rather than 0 - thus the first slide `"disappears"`

```js
/*
  As a self-executing anonymous function that
  calls setTimeout within a new anon function
  to run indefinitely.
*/
const _DELAY=2.5;



(function(time){
  // create an array from HTML elements in the slide carousel
  let col=Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('img.mySlides') );
  let i=0;

  (function(){
    setTimeout( arguments.callee, time * 1000 );
    
    // hide the other slides
    if( i >= col.length )i=0;
    col.forEach( n=>n.style.display='none' );
    
    // select next image
    let img=col[i];
        img.style.display='block';
        
    // to show the progress
    console.log(i,img.src)
    i++;

  })();
})( _DELAY );
```

```html
<section>
  <img class="mySlides" src="photo/banner.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="photo/banner2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="photo/banner3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="photo/banner4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="photo/banner5.jpg" style="width:100%">
</section>
```